# Limiting the scope of schemas when GRANT/REVOKE'ing in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, schema

In postgres, you can `GRANT` or `REVOKE` privileges like:

```
REVOKE ALL ON SCHEMA public FROM PUBLIC;
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA public TO <myuser>;
```

My question;  If each database has a schema `PUBLIC`, then are you revoking or granting for this *all* databases?  If so, what if you only want to alter the schema permissions of one database?

The context:  I want to `GRANT SELECT, INSERT, DELETE` to one user for only one scheme in one database.  I want to do this without being connected to the DB.  Or is the way to do this simply by also handling `CONNECT` permissions to actual databases.  So if they can only connect to one database, it doesn't matter if you say "all" PUBLIC schemas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of questions here; I'll try to restore order.

1. It is a good idea to revoke `CREATE` from the `public` schema in all databases.

   But you absolutely have to connect to each database in turn to do that.

   A beautiful solution might be that you do it on database `template1`. Then every new database will automatically be set up correctly, since `CREATE DATABASE` copies the template database.
2. To give users permission to a schema in all databases, you again have to connect to all databases in turn.
3. It is also a good idea to `REVOKE ALL` on all databases from `PUBLIC` and grant the `CONNECT` privilege selectively.

   This time, you can do it without connecting to each database, because databases are shared objects — the `pg_database` catalog is accessible from each database.